# Dúvida com DATEDIFF intervalo de dias entre datas

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma consulta que preciso retornar o intervalo de dias, o problema é que os campos de data está definido como varchar(30).

```html
  --a data teria que ficar assim
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2015/12/16','2015/12/20') AS DiffDate 
  --data está gravada assim no banco como varchar(30)
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'16/12/2015','16/12/2015') AS DiffDate
```

```html
  select a.*, 
  DATEDIFF(DAY,a.EMISSAO,a.VENCIMENTO) as Dias 
  from TB_DOCUMENTOS_ABERTOS a
  inner join TB_CLIENTE b on a.CODIGOCLIENTE = b.CODIGO
  ORDER BY b.RAZAO
```

Erro:
Mensagem 241, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx) dessa forma:

```
 REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, @data, 103), '-','/')
```

Depois calcula o DIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, emissao, 103), '-','/'),REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, vencimento, 103), '-','/')) AS DiffDate
```